# failed to build codeblocks smith wxWidget project

Tags: c++, c, wxwidgets, codeblocks, windows-7-x64

I am trying to setup code::blocks smith to do wxWidgets GUI programming. Recently I installed code::blocks and wxWidget libraries to my PC.

```
code::blocks IDE version: 13.12
wxWidget version: 2.8.12
Operating System: Windows 7
```

Below is the build log for the wxWidget project. I followed the instructions listed in wxWidget web site but didn't work.

```
-------------- Build: Debug in CsBarcodeScanner (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_lib\mswud -c C:\Data\CsBarcodeScanner\wx_pch.h -o wx_pch.h.gch\Debug_wx_pch_h_gch
In file included from C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/platform.h:293:0,
                 from C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/defs.h:21,
                 from C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/wxprec.h:13,
                 from ./wx_pch.h:14,
                 from <command-line>:0:
C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include/wx/chkconf.h:1817:9: error: #error "wxClipboard requires wxDataObject"
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you edited `wx/setup.h` file? By default, `wxUSE_DATAOBJECT` should be set to 1 in it so I don't see how can this error occur with unmodified sources.

Also, I'd *strongly* recommend using wxWidgets 3.0, there is absolutely no reason to use 2.8 for a new project.

Comment: I setup everything again, I have below problem.

C:\wxWidgets-3.0.0\include/wx/platform.h:189:22: fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory

Comment: This file is created during the build of wxWidgets. Did you build it actually?

Comment: No, actually I didn't know about it. This is first time I am going to use it. Thanks.

Comment: @Nish 
The path to the setup.h for Windows is include/wx/msw/setup.h
U can edit the platform.h file to fix the issue. In platform.h use wx/msw/setup.h